# Sitecore EXM Unsubscribe Notification

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-exm

When I am unsubscribing form EXM subscription list, I am receiving email from not_reply@yoursite.net. Is there any way to override yoursite.net domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the Subscription Form control to a page, in the Control Properties dialog box, in the Control Options group, you can change the properties that are specific to the control.

You have a manager root field. The module uses subscription confirmation pages and notification emails from the manager root that you select.

[image]

**Update**

On item /sitecore/content/Home/Manager Root/Messages/Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Unsubscribe Notification (this is my manager root item I have a field From Address that has default value :not_reply@yoursite.net

Please check below image:

[image]

Comment: I did not see any setting in my manager root field as not_reply@yoursite.net. Am I missing anything here?